# X server broken by Free CAD?

Tags: xorg

I'm typing this on my phone, so bear with me until I make it to a computer.

I have been running Gubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo G500 for about a year, with other ubuntu distros years before that.

Yesterday, my laptop worked perfectly. Last night I first installed BRL-CAD, but then decided Free CAD looked better and installed that, also. I vaguely remember seeing one of the two say it was removing packages, and I think that is the root of the problem.

In fact it might have been BRL-CAD. Here are the [dependencies](http://brlcad.org/wiki/Compiling#Install_Dependencies) I believe it was the X related packages that removed some when they were installed.

So this morning I go to login to my laptop, and on the screen where you type in the password it kept saying authentication failed, as of the enter button were being continually clicked. This prevented me from entering my password without interruption, so I restart my computer. Next thing I know, my computer is hanging at the splash screen. I restart in recovery mode, and then try to boot and it appears to be hanging on Restoring resolver state. Upon googling this only happened on distro upgrades, it seems??

So I reboot into recovery mode again, turn on network, run the dpkg tool, open root console, run apt-get update/upgrade for redundancy sake, and shutdown the computer.

I try to boot again, still hangs on splash screen. I open a terminal with alt + ctrl + F2. I am able to log in. I try to enter startx, screen goes blank for a moment then returns to prompt, with this output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I am typing this on my now fixed laptop!

The problem was, indeed, something to do with those [dependency packages](http://brlcad.org/wiki/Compiling#Install_Dependencies) from BRL-CAD. So I removed all of those packages, as well as xserver

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libx11-dev 
sudo apt-get remove --purge libxi-dev 
sudo apt-get remove --purge libxt-dev 
sudo apt-get remove --purge libxau-dev 
sudo apt-get remove --purge libxext-dev 
sudo apt-get remove --purge libxmu-dev 
sudo apt-get remove --purge libxmu-headers
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get remove --purge brlcad
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now we need to reinstall the necessary packages.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xinit
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

From there I restarted the computer and I was greeted by my desktop.